# Why does "The Witcher" series, being mostly about shades of grey instead of black and white, have such an obviously evil antagonist?

Tags: polish-language, the-witcher, andrzej-sapkowski

It's a point that pops some what frequently in the series, that there's no real "good" and "evil" (or rather, that's Geralt's point of view), and there's only the "lesser evil", and the hardest part, of course, is to choose it from all the other evils.

Yet the main antagonist,

> Vilgefortz,

is simply evil. He simply admits his only goal is world domination, and he won't hesitate to perform vile experiments on young girls to obtain it.

Among the cast of other characters, who have personalities and different traits, he seems extremely flat. Why is that?

Comment: If there's only the lesser evil, there must be a greater one. ;)

Comment: I think it's rather black/grey then grey/grey world. There are various ambiguous characters and there are twisted depraved sorcerers and their bloodthirsty creations that need to be slain, whatever it takes. *Season of Storms* is especially this, so maybe it's just the direction where things started to go somewhere along the road.